# Handle "Permission denied" inside the script

Tags: bash, scripting

I make a script, one of the functions receives information from remote servers via ssh:

```
session_check() {
    ssh -o BatchMode=yes $USER@$SERVER my_command | grep "value" > /dev/null
}
```

As planned, access will be using keys, but if the keys are not loaded on the remote machine, I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

I cannot use the returning 0 or 1, since 1 will be returned in the same way if access to the server is successful, but the command is unsuccessful. I need to somehow hide the "Permission denied" message and make a condition that will be met only if such a message is received.

I hope I wrote it clearly. Thanks in advance!

**upd**
I figured out how to use stderr ( `2>> (grep "value")` ), but I still can't use it with the function above.
So I need to redirect stderr somewhere for later use. But in order to somehow get a ruselt from the execution of the command on the server, if it was possible to connect to the server.
I suspect that this is generally impossible with one command and I need to first check if the connection is successful, and then execute the command. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

In your script, because you are using a pipe, you are already ignoring the exit status of `my_command`; the exit status of the pipeline will be the exit status of the last command in the pipe.

Bash lets you inspect the exit code from any command in the pipeline, though; now you just have to make sure that your remote command always succeeds. Because you were already ignoring its exit status, we are not introducing any new bugs with this.

```sh
session_check() {
    ssh -o BatchMode=yes $USER@$SERVER 'my_command; exit 0' | grep -q "value"
    local rc=$?
    if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 ]]; then
        return 127
    fi
    return $rc
}
```

If you want to reap the exit status of `my_command` as well, that's going to be significantly harder; perhaps then split this into two separate commands.

```sh
session_check() {
    status=$(ssh -o BatchMode=yes $USER@$SERVER 'my_command; echo $?') &&
    sed '$d' <<<"$status" | grep -q "value"
    return $(sed -n '$p' <<<"$status")
}
```

Notice how we are smuggling out the exit code as the last line of textual output from the `ssh` command, and then traversing it repeatedly.  This should probably be refactored for efficiency, but at least shows a way to implement this if you need it.

Notice that we are using several Bash-only features here; the script needs to have `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` in the shebang.

The need for this sort of chicanery is an indication that you are near the boundaries of what's feasible to do in terms of controlled error handling in the shell's processing model. Perhaps you would want to explore rewriting some or all of this in a modern scripting language like Python.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it; this helps others see that the problem was resolved. See also [help.](/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a new user and can't do this until my reputation is higher than 15...

Comment: `ssh` actually does return the exit status of the remote command. So if you do `ssh somehost "exit 123"`, you get `123` in the local `$?`. Also, it returns `255` if it can't connect, so usually you can tell that that apart from other error returns. Maybe you get 255 also if the connection closes due to an error or other such cases, probably doesn't matter here. Also, shells use `126` and `127` to indicate the cases "can't execute file", and "command not found", so using those for other situations may have a slight chance of confusion.

Comment: Accepting an answer requires no reputation at all.